# Wireless configuration using /etc/network/interfaces documentation

Tags: wireless, configuration, interface, documentation

I followed the tutorial here and was able to properly configure my network: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202834&page=181

I know of the documentation in `/usr/share/doc/wireless-tools/README.Debian`, but it doesn't detail the options that were used.

Where can I find the documentation for the settings that were used? For example, where can I find the documentation on the options (`wpa-ssid`, `wpa-psk`, etc.)?

Comment: old thread but found more useful link for wireless setting [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318539)

Answer (score 7):

I'm googling for the same thing, here is what I found.

Arguments prefixed with "wpa-",which are used for `wpa_supplicant Managed Mode`,are documented in `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz`.

Arguments in form of `wireless-<function>` are equivalent to `iwconfig <interface> <function> <value>`, so the usage can refer to [iwconfig(8) manpages](http://manpages.debian.net/man/8/iwconfig).

Answer (score 6):

Change accordingly

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid myssid
    wpa-psk a1b2c3d4e5
```

Comment: Does the myssid need quotes like "myssid" and "a1b2c3d4e5" ?

Comment: @DougA you don't need quotes.

Comment: If you have special characters or spaces these don't need to be escaped, e.g. `wpa-ssid My Wi-Fi Network`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102530/escape-characters-in-etc-network-interfaces